# Solidity Error: We were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the contract and this transaction may fail

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js, erc20

I have dapp web app with smart contract deployed on rinkeby testnet.
In my dapp website, I have token swap and stake function.
Link:  https://doxa-staking.netlify.app
When I swap my ether for my token it works fine. Now on the dapp stake function, when I first stake a token it works fine but I cant stake another one for a second time. Whenever I want to stake the remaining token or just stake a part of the token, I get the cant estimate gas error.

These are the errors I get:

> Fail with error 'Value is less than the minium ETH'

> Warning: Error encountered during contract execution - execution reverted

Link to the transaction error:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xa4976881e4762e13e634cad1189d851a9182f3b4d6f1ea6bbfd64ebf2e22424c.

Link to the staking smart contract codes:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xb1fed59cc80145ba05a0c248b55c0631a363f780#code.
Link to the token smart contract code:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xd99b4bb049a6dd490901cdfa33f15c4fac097ef0#code.

My dapp reactjs source code link:
https://github.com/isofttechn/staking-dapp/blob/main/src/components/Home/index.js
I dont really know if the error is coming from the smart contract or the dapp itself.

The staking smart contract to which the error is coming from

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;


library AddressUpgradeable {
    
    function isContract(address account) internal view returns (bool) {
       
        return account.code.length > 0;
    }

    function sendValue(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) internal {
        require(address(this).balance >= amount, "Address: insufficient balance");

        (bool success, ) = recipient.call{value: amount}("");
        require(success, "Address: unable to send value, recipient may have reverted");
    }

    function functionCall(address target, bytes memory data) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        return functionCall(target, data, "Address: low-level call failed");
    }

    function functionCall(
        address target,
        bytes memory data,
        string memory errorMessage
    ) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        return functionCallWithValue(target, data, 0, errorMessage);
    }

    function functionCallWithValue(
        address target,
        bytes memory data,
        uint256 value
    ) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        return functionCallWithValue(target, data, value, "Address: low-level call with value failed");
    }

    function functionCallWithValue(
        address target,
        bytes memory data,
        uint256 value,
        string memory errorMessage
    ) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        require(address(this).balance >= value, "Address: insufficient balance for call");
        require(isContract(target), "Address: call to non-contract");

        (bool success, bytes memory returndata) = target.call{value: value}(data);
        return verifyCallResult(success, returndata, errorMessage);
    }

    function functionStaticCall(address target, bytes memory data) internal view returns (bytes memory) {
        return functionStaticCall(target, data, "Address: low-level static call failed");
    }

    function functionStaticCall(
        address target,
        bytes memory data,
        string memory errorMessage
    ) internal view returns (bytes memory) {
        require(isContract(target), "Address: static call to non-contract");

        (bool success, bytes memory returndata) = target.staticcall(data);
        return verifyCallResult(success, returndata, errorMessage);
    }

    function verifyCallResult(
        bool success,
        bytes memory returndata,
        string memory errorMessage
    ) internal pure returns (bytes memory) {
        if (success) {
            return returndata;
        } else {
            if (returndata.length > 0) {
                assembly {
                    let returndata_size := mload(returndata)
                    revert(add(32, returndata), returndata_size)
                }
            } else {
                revert(errorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

abstract contract Initializable {
    bool private _initialized;

    bool private _initializing;
    modifier initializer() {
        require(_initializing ? _isConstructor() : !_initialized, "Initializable: contract is already initialized");

        bool isTopLevelCall = !_initializing;
        if (isTopLevelCall) {
            _initializing = true;
            _initialized = true;
        }

        _;

        if (isTopLevelCall) {
            _initializing = false;
        }
    }

    modifier onlyInitializing() {
        require(_initializing, "Initializable: contract is not initializing");
        _;
    }

    function _isConstructor() private view returns (bool) {
        return !AddressUpgradeable.isContract(address(this));
    }
}

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
abstract contract ContextUpgradeable is Initializable {
    function __Context_init() internal onlyInitializing {
    }

    function __Context_init_unchained() internal onlyInitializing {
    }
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes calldata) {
        return msg.data;
    }
    uint256[50] private __gap;
}

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
abstract contract OwnableUpgradeable is Initializable, ContextUpgradeable {
    address private _owner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);
    function __Ownable_init() internal onlyInitializing {
        __Ownable_init_unchained();
    }

    function __Ownable_init_unchained() internal onlyInitializing {
        _transferOwnership(_msgSender());
    }
    function owner() public view virtual returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(owner() == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
        _;
    }

    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        _transferOwnership(address(0));
    }
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        _transferOwnership(newOwner);
    }
    function _transferOwnership(address newOwner) internal virtual {
        address oldOwner = _owner;
        _owner = newOwner;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(oldOwner, newOwner);
    }
    uint256[49] private __gap;
}

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
interface IERC20Upgradeable {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

library Strings {
    bytes16 private constant _HEX_SYMBOLS = "0123456789abcdef";

    function toString(uint256 value) internal pure returns (string memory) {

        if (value == 0) {
            return "0";
        }
        uint256 temp = value;
        uint256 digits;
        while (temp != 0) {
            digits++;
            temp /= 10;
        }
        bytes memory buffer = new bytes(digits);
        while (value != 0) {
            digits -= 1;
            buffer[digits] = bytes1(uint8(48 + uint256(value % 10)));
            value /= 10;
        }
        return string(buffer);
    }

    function toHexString(uint256 value) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        if (value == 0) {
            return "0x00";
        }
        uint256 temp = value;
        uint256 length = 0;
        while (temp != 0) {
            length++;
            temp >>= 8;
        }
        return toHexString(value, length);
    }

    function toHexString(uint256 value, uint256 length) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory buffer = new bytes(2 * length + 2);
        buffer[0] = "0";
        buffer[1] = "x";
        for (uint256 i = 2 * length + 1; i > 1; --i) {
            buffer[i] = _HEX_SYMBOLS[value & 0xf];
            value >>= 4;
        }
        require(value == 0, "Strings: hex length insufficient");
        return string(buffer);
    }
}

library ECDSA {
    enum RecoverError {
        NoError,
        InvalidSignature,
        InvalidSignatureLength,
        InvalidSignatureS,
        InvalidSignatureV
    }

    function _throwError(RecoverError error) private pure {
        if (error == RecoverError.NoError) {
            return; // no error: do nothing
        } else if (error == RecoverError.InvalidSignature) {
            revert("ECDSA: invalid signature");
        } else if (error == RecoverError.InvalidSignatureLength) {
            revert("ECDSA: invalid signature length");
        } else if (error == RecoverError.InvalidSignatureS) {
            revert("ECDSA: invalid signature 's' value");
        } else if (error == RecoverError.InvalidSignatureV) {
            revert("ECDSA: invalid signature 'v' value");
        }
    }

    function tryRecover(bytes32 hash, bytes memory signature) internal pure returns (address, RecoverError) {
        if (signature.length == 65) {
            bytes32 r;
            bytes32 s;
            uint8 v;
            assembly {
                r := mload(add(signature, 0x20))
                s := mload(add(signature, 0x40))
                v := byte(0, mload(add(signature, 0x60)))
            }
            return tryRecover(hash, v, r, s);
        } else if (signature.length == 64) {
            bytes32 r;
            bytes32 vs;

            assembly {
                r := mload(add(signature, 0x20))
                vs := mload(add(signature, 0x40))
            }
            return tryRecover(hash, r, vs);
        } else {
            return (address(0), RecoverError.InvalidSignatureLength);
        }
    }

    function recover(bytes32 hash, bytes memory signature) internal pure returns (address) {
        (address recovered, RecoverError error) = tryRecover(hash, signature);
        _throwError(error);
        return recovered;
    }
    function tryRecover(
        bytes32 hash,
        bytes32 r,
        bytes32 vs
    ) internal pure returns (address, RecoverError) {
        bytes32 s = vs & bytes32(0x7fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff);
        uint8 v = uint8((uint256(vs) >> 255) + 27);
        return tryRecover(hash, v, r, s);
    }

    function recover(
        bytes32 hash,
        bytes32 r,
        bytes32 vs
    ) internal pure returns (address) {
        (address recovered, RecoverError error) = tryRecover(hash, r, vs);
        _throwError(error);
        return recovered;
    }

    function tryRecover(
        bytes32 hash,
        uint8 v,
        bytes32 r,
        bytes32 s
    ) internal pure returns (address, RecoverError) {

        if (uint256(s) > 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF5D576E7357A4501DDFE92F46681B20A0) {
            return (address(0), RecoverError.InvalidSignatureS);
        }
        if (v != 27 && v != 28) {
            return (address(0), RecoverError.InvalidSignatureV);
        }

        address signer = ecrecover(hash, v, r, s);
        if (signer == address(0)) {
            return (address(0), RecoverError.InvalidSignature);
        }

        return (signer, RecoverError.NoError);
    }

    function recover(
        bytes32 hash,
        uint8 v,
        bytes32 r,
        bytes32 s
    ) internal pure returns (address) {
        (address recovered, RecoverError error) = tryRecover(hash, v, r, s);
        _throwError(error);
        return recovered;
    }

    function toEthSignedMessageHash(bytes32 hash) internal pure returns (bytes32) {

        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", hash));
    }

    function toEthSignedMessageHash(bytes memory s) internal pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n", Strings.toString(s.length), s));
    }

    function toTypedDataHash(bytes32 domainSeparator, bytes32 structHash) internal pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19\x01", domainSeparator, structHash));
    }
}


abstract contract EIP712 {
    bytes32 private immutable _CACHED_DOMAIN_SEPARATOR;
    uint256 private immutable _CACHED_CHAIN_ID;
    address private immutable _CACHED_THIS;

    bytes32 private immutable _HASHED_NAME;
    bytes32 private immutable _HASHED_VERSION;
    bytes32 private immutable _TYPE_HASH;

    constructor(string memory name, string memory version) {
        bytes32 hashedName = keccak256(bytes(name));
        bytes32 hashedVersion = keccak256(bytes(version));
        bytes32 typeHash = keccak256(
            "EIP712Domain(string name,string version,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract)"
        );
        _HASHED_NAME = hashedName;
        _HASHED_VERSION = hashedVersion;
        _CACHED_CHAIN_ID = block.chainid;
        _CACHED_DOMAIN_SEPARATOR = _buildDomainSeparator(typeHash, hashedName, hashedVersion);
        _CACHED_THIS = address(this);
        _TYPE_HASH = typeHash;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the domain separator for the current chain.
     */
    function _domainSeparatorV4() internal view returns (bytes32) {
        if (address(this) == _CACHED_THIS && block.chainid == _CACHED_CHAIN_ID) {
            return _CACHED_DOMAIN_SEPARATOR;
        } else {
            return _buildDomainSeparator(_TYPE_HASH, _HASHED_NAME, _HASHED_VERSION);
        }
    }

    function _buildDomainSeparator(
        bytes32 typeHash,
        bytes32 nameHash,
        bytes32 versionHash
    ) private view returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encode(typeHash, nameHash, versionHash, block.chainid, address(this)));
    }

    function _hashTypedDataV4(bytes32 structHash) internal view virtual returns (bytes32) {
        return ECDSA.toTypedDataHash(_domainSeparatorV4(), structHash);
    }
}






contract whitelistChecker is EIP712 {

    string private constant SIGNING_DOMAIN = "Azo_Staking";
    string private constant SIGNATURE_VERSION = "1";

     struct Whitelist {
        address userAddress;
        address contractAddress;
        uint256 amount;
        uint256 id;
        uint256 noOfDays ;
        uint256 timestamp;
        bytes signature;
    }
    constructor() EIP712(SIGNING_DOMAIN, SIGNATURE_VERSION){

    }

    function getSigner(Whitelist memory whitelist) public view returns(address){
        return _verify(whitelist);
    }

    /// @notice Returns a hash of the given whitelist, prepared using EIP712 typed data hashing rules.

function _hash(Whitelist memory whitelist) internal view returns (bytes32) {
        return _hashTypedDataV4(keccak256(abi.encode(
                keccak256("Whitelist(address userAddress,address contractAddress,uint256 amount,uint256 id,uint256 noOfDays,uint256 timestamp)"),
                whitelist.userAddress,
                whitelist.contractAddress,
                whitelist.amount,
                whitelist.id,
                whitelist.noOfDays,
                whitelist.timestamp
            )));
    }
    function _verify(Whitelist memory whitelist) internal view returns (address) {
        bytes32 digest = _hash(whitelist);
        return ECDSA.recover(digest, whitelist.signature);
    }

}



contract doxaStake is OwnableUpgradeable,whitelistChecker{

    IERC20Upgradeable public stakeToken;
    IERC20Upgradeable public rewardToken;

    uint256 private _totalSupply;
    address public signer;
    uint256 public givenRewards;

    uint256 public totalRewardFunds;
    uint256 public rewardBalance = totalRewardFunds;

    uint day = 60;
    uint accuracyFactor = 10 ** 10;

    mapping(address => uint256) public totalStakeRecords;
    mapping(address => mapping (uint => bool)) private usedNonce;
    mapping(address => stakerDetails[]) public Stakers;
    mapping(address=>bool) public isBlocklisted;
       modifier isblocklist(address _addr){
        require(!isBlocklisted[_addr],"wallet is blocklisted");
        _;
    }

      struct stakerDetails {
        uint id;
        uint balance;
        uint totalRewards;
        uint lockingPeriod;
        uint lastUpdatedTime;
        uint maxTime;
        uint rewardEarned;
        uint rewardPaidOut;
        uint apr;
    }

    event RewardAdded(uint256 reward);
    event Staked(address indexed user, uint256 amount, uint256 noOfDays);
    event Unstaked(address indexed user, uint256 amount);
    event RewardPaid(address indexed user, uint256 reward);
    event RecoverToken(address indexed token, uint256 indexed amount);
    modifier updateReward(address account, uint id) {
        Stakers[account][id].rewardEarned = earned(account, id);
        _;
    }

    function getRewardRate(address account, uint id) public view returns (uint256) {
        uint daysInTimestamp = Stakers[account][id].lockingPeriod * day;

        uint amount = getAmountWithApr(account, id);

        return (amount*(Stakers[account][id].lockingPeriod))/(daysInTimestamp*(365));
    }

    function getAmountWithApr(address account, uint id) internal view returns(uint) {
        return ((Stakers[account][id].balance) * (Stakers[account][id].apr))/(100 *accuracyFactor);
    }

    function earned(address account, uint id) public view returns (uint256) {
        if(Stakers[account][id].rewardPaidOut < Stakers[account][id].totalRewards) {
            if(block.timestamp >= Stakers[account][id].maxTime) {
              return (Stakers[account][id].totalRewards)-(Stakers[account][id].rewardPaidOut);
            }

            return
               (getRewardRate(account, id)) * ((block.timestamp)-(Stakers[account][id].lastUpdatedTime));
        } else {
            return 0;
        } 
    }

    function isRewardAvailable(uint rewardAmount) public view returns (bool) {
        if(rewardBalance >= rewardAmount) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function getAPR(uint noOfDays) public view returns(uint) {
         require(noOfDays <=365,"Only 1 year");
      return ((noOfDays * (5 * (noOfDays * accuracyFactor)) /(10000)) + (50 * accuracyFactor));
    }

    function rewardForPeriod(uint amount, uint noOfDays) public view returns (uint) {
         require(noOfDays <=365,"Only 1 year");
        uint apr = getAPR(noOfDays);
        uint reward = (amount *apr)/((100) * (accuracyFactor));
        uint totalRewardForPeriod = (reward/365) *(noOfDays);
        require(isRewardAvailable(totalRewardForPeriod), "Not enought reward available");
        return totalRewardForPeriod;
    }

    function stake(uint256 amount, uint noOfDays,  Whitelist memory stakeo) external isblocklist(msg.sender){
        require(noOfDays <=365,"Only 1 year");
        require(!usedNonce[msg.sender][stakeo.timestamp],"Nonce : Invalid Nonce");
        require (getSigner(stakeo) == signer,'!Signer');
        usedNonce[msg.sender][stakeo.timestamp] = true;
        require(amount > 0, "Cannot stake 0");
        stakerDetails memory staker;

        uint daysInTimestamp = noOfDays * day;

        uint rewardForUser = rewardForPeriod(amount, noOfDays);
        totalStakeRecords[msg.sender] += 1;
        staker.id = totalStakeRecords[msg.sender];
        staker.lockingPeriod = noOfDays;
        staker.totalRewards = rewardForUser;
        staker.lastUpdatedTime = block.timestamp;
        staker.maxTime = block.timestamp + (daysInTimestamp);
        staker.balance = amount;
        staker.apr = getAPR(noOfDays);

        Stakers[msg.sender].push(staker);
        rewardBalance -= rewardForUser;
        _totalSupply +=amount;
        stakeToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        emit Staked(msg.sender, amount, noOfDays);
    }

    function unstake(uint id, Whitelist memory stakeo) internal {
        require(!usedNonce[msg.sender][stakeo.timestamp],"Nonce : Invalid Nonce");
        require (getSigner(stakeo) == signer,'!Signer');
        usedNonce[msg.sender][stakeo.timestamp] = true;
        require(block.timestamp >= Stakers[msg.sender][id].maxTime, "Tokens are locked! Try unstaking after locking period");
        uint amount = Stakers[msg.sender][id].balance;
        _totalSupply -=amount;
        Stakers[msg.sender][id].balance = 0;
        stakeToken.transfer(msg.sender, amount);
        emit Unstaked(msg.sender, amount);
    }


    function getReward(uint id,Whitelist memory stakeo) external  updateReward(msg.sender, id) isblocklist(msg.sender){
        require(!usedNonce[msg.sender][stakeo.timestamp],"Nonce : Invalid Nonce");
        require (getSigner(stakeo) == signer,'!Signer');
        usedNonce[msg.sender][stakeo.timestamp] = true;
        uint256 reward = earned(msg.sender, id);
        require(reward>0,"no Rewards Available");
        Stakers[msg.sender][id].lastUpdatedTime = block.timestamp;
        if (reward > 0) {
            Stakers[msg.sender][id].rewardEarned = 0;
            Stakers[msg.sender][id].rewardPaidOut += reward;
            givenRewards+=reward;
            rewardToken.transfer(msg.sender, reward);
            emit RewardPaid(msg.sender, reward);
        }
    }

     function exit(uint id,Whitelist memory stakeo) external isblocklist(msg.sender){
        require(!usedNonce[msg.sender][stakeo.timestamp],"Nonce : Invalid Nonce");
        require (getSigner(stakeo) == signer,'!Signer');
        usedNonce[msg.sender][stakeo.timestamp] = true;
        require(block.timestamp >= Stakers[msg.sender][id].maxTime, "Tokens are locked! Try unstaking after locking period");
         uint amount = Stakers[msg.sender][id].balance;
        require(amount>0,"No staked Balance");
        uint256 reward = earned(msg.sender, id);
        Stakers[msg.sender][id].lastUpdatedTime = block.timestamp;
        if (reward > 0) {
            Stakers[msg.sender][id].rewardEarned = 0;
            givenRewards+=reward;
            Stakers[msg.sender][id].rewardPaidOut += reward;
            rewardToken.transfer(msg.sender, reward);
            emit RewardPaid(msg.sender, reward);
        }
         _totalSupply -=amount;
        Stakers[msg.sender][id].balance = 0;
        stakeToken.transfer(msg.sender, amount);
          emit Unstaked(msg.sender, amount);
    }


    function TotalValueLocked() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function setsigner(address _addr) external onlyOwner{
        signer=_addr;
    }

    function balanceOf(address account, uint id) public view returns (uint256) {
        return Stakers[account][id].balance;
    }

    function recoverExcessToken(address token, uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {
        IERC20Upgradeable(token).transfer(msg.sender, amount);
        emit RecoverToken(token, amount);
    }

    function depositRewards(uint amount) public onlyOwner {
        stakeToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        totalRewardFunds += amount;
        rewardBalance += amount;
    }
    function TotalRewards() public view returns(uint256){
        uint256 tRewards = totalRewardFunds - rewardBalance;
        return tRewards;
    }
    
    function blocklistUsers(address _addr) external onlyOwner{
        isBlocklisted[_addr]=true;
    }
    function unblockUsers(address _addr) external onlyOwner{
         isBlocklisted[_addr]=false;
    }
    function initialize(address _stakeToken, address _RewardToken) external initializer{
          stakeToken=IERC20Upgradeable(_stakeToken);
          rewardToken=IERC20Upgradeable(_RewardToken);
              __Ownable_init();
           signer=msg.sender;
    }
    function setTokens(address _addr) external onlyOwner{
         stakeToken=IERC20Upgradeable(_addr);
         rewardToken=IERC20Upgradeable(_addr);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be quit lots of factors that led to this error. I'll try and give just one solution, but you could try and explore other solution out there.

If you deployed your smart contract using remix, redeploy it using hardhat.

Then, in your hardhat.config.js, add manual gas limit in networks:

```
your network: {
    url: `https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/${process.env.PROJECT_ID}`,
    accounts: [privateKey],
    gas: 2100000,
    gasPrice: 8000000000,
}
```

In your index.js file, instead of mainnet in Web3Modal, use your network:

```
const web3Modal = new Web3Modal({
    network: "your network name",
    cacheProvider: true,
})
```

That should work; however, you could explore other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It may happens due to latest version of web3, try using **web3@1.8.1** version.